# ColdFusion Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token jQuery

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am getting the following console error

> (Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token)

in my staging environment, but not in my DEV or TEST environment. Any ideas? I'm completely stumped.

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $.sessionTimeout({
                warnAfter: 1500000, // 5000 (10 seconds) | 1500000 (25 minutes)
                redirAfter: 1800000, // 15000 (20 seconds) | 1800000 (30 minutes)
                Line Highlighted --- > keepAliveUrl: '[URL.Path]/keepalive.cfm',
                logoutUrl: '[URL.Path]/logout.cfm',
                redirUrl: '[URL.Path]/logout.cfm?sessiontimeout=[URL.Path]/removeddashboard.cfm%3F',
                countdownMessage: 'Your session will expire in {timer}',
                message: 'Please be advised that per OIMT guidelines, sessions of inactivity for applications can be no longer than 30 minutes.'
                });
            });
            </script>
```

Also, does anyone know why the browser is cutting off the string and making it on two lines and might that be the issue??

Comment: if you are using CDN maybe your staging environment doesn't have output to Internet inside the VPN

Comment: Your result is not as expected - used the network tab on the browser to determine exactly what is being returned - it might be an HTML error page.

Comment: Nothing going on in the Network tab.

Comment: Also, does anyone know why the browser is cutting off the string and making it on two lines and might that be the issue??

Comment: What happened when you got rid of the line breaks?

Comment: @SOS Once I removed the line breaks the error went away.

Comment: Makes sense. Write up an answer explaining the line breaks were the issue (and what caused them, if relevant)

Answer (score 0):

I made the URLs a relative path to make shorter and the error issue went away.